# Select rows of a master table that contains two distinct indexes to records on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Given these two tables where `idcontype` and `idinfcontype` in `containers` are related to `id` in `contypes`.
I need a query that returns a `containers` row with `descrip` columns for both `idcontype` and `idinfcontype`.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `containers`
-- 

`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idarticle` int(11) NOT NULL,
`idzone` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`idcontype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`idinfcontype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',


--
-- Table structure for table `contypes`
--

`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` char(1) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
`level` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`descrip` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
```

`idcontype` and `idinfcontype` in `containers` are related to `id` in `contypes`
`idcontype` always relates to an `id` in `contypes` but `idinfcontype` may be `0`

This query generates three rows with a duplicate row

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(SELECT `containers`.`id`,`idarticle`,`idcontype`,`descrip` FROM `containers` JOIN `contypes` ON   containers.idcontype=contypes.id
UNION
SELECT `containers`.`id`,`idarticle`,`idinfcontype`,`descrip` FROM `containers` JOIN `contypes` ON containers.idinfcontype=contypes.id
) CT

Rows: 3

id  idarticle   idcontype   descrip
1   2           1           PACKAGE
2   2           2           BOX
2   2           1           PACKAGE
```

After some struggle this query produces the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM `containers`
JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT id AS idc FROM
(SELECT `containers`.`id`,`idarticle`,`idcontype`,`descrip` FROM `containers` JOIN `contypes` ON         containers.idcontype=contypes.id
UNION
SELECT `containers`.`id`,`idarticle`,`idinfcontype`,`descrip` FROM `containers` JOIN `contypes` ON containers.idinfcontype=contypes.id
) CT ) CTD
ON containers.id=idc

id  idarticle   idcontype   descrip
1   2           1           PACKAGE
2   2           2           BOX
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you would approach this with `left join`s:

```
SELECT c.*, ct.descrip, ctinf.descrip as infdescrip
FROM containers c LEFT JOIN
     contypes ct
     on c.idcontype = ct.id LEFT JOIN
     contypes ctinf
     on c.idinfcontype = ctinf.id;
```

In addition to the `left join`, this query:

- Uses table aliases.  These are needed in this case because the query has the same table twice in the `from` clause.
- Uses column aliases to distinguish between the two columns.
- Doesn't use backticks.  These are not necessary and I'm of the opinion that they make queries harder to read and write.

Comment: Neat! Thks. Agree on the backticks

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the same table multiple times by using correlation names:

```
SELECT `containers`.`id`,`idarticle`,`idcontype`,`contypes`.`descrip`, 'idinfcontype', c2.'descrip' 
FROM `containers` 
JOIN `contypes` ON   containers.idcontype='contypes'.contypes.id
JOIN `contypes` c2 ON containers.idinfcontype=c2.id
```

The second contypes table has a correlation name of c2 specified. The first contypes table has no correlation name supplied, so uses the table name itself as the correlation name. This latter applies to the containers table too.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''descrip' 
FROM `containers` 
JOIN `contypes` ON   containers.idcontype='contype' at line 1

Comment: Checked it again. Back ticks cause the syntaz error. Solved that LEFT JOIN is necessary, otherwise a 0 idinfcontype does not return a row. Thks.